# Calculate the amount of Primecoin(XPM) mined/created so far

Tags: currencies

According to Wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primecoin

the reward given for finding a block is 999*(difficulty**2). So does that mean that you need historic data on the difficulty in order to calculate how many coins there are?

Comment: It's 999/(difficulty^2), not 999*(difficulty^2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, unlike Bitcoin you can't deduce the total number of coins in circulation from the current block height, you need historic difficulty data. Of course, there should be services that have already computed this and present it publicly.

Comment: By any chance do you know any services that offer the number of coins in circulation as an API?

Comment: @PeterVasilev: http://primecoin.21stcenturymoneytalk.org/ has this and other data about Primecoin. I found this via http://coinmarketcap.com/ which lists data about several coins.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that one too. However, they don't have any sort of working API